# db2 error message when I open first steps window

Tags: windows, installation, db2, sample

please help me with this error message that I see after finishing the installation of db2 in windows and start the first steps window

[image]

I tried to create sample database and it doesnt work also:

[image]

Comment: It may be better to put this question on dba.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db2 , because it is not a programming question.  Also EDIT your question to add vital missing facts, the details of the Windows(bitness, version, home/pro/server/ docker / vm etc), how much RAM is available, the full text output of `db2level`  (as text not pictures). Is the Db2-server started? Are you running as local administrator? Also which instructions you followed for installation and configuration of the Db2-server. Usually there is more information in the db2diag.log file, admin log file etc.